# JQuery auto resize textareas

Tags: jquery

I have a function that auto resizes textareas

```
function textarea_resize() {
    //  changes mouse cursor when highlighting loawer right of box
    $("textarea.autoresize").on('keyup', function(e) {
        var myPos = $(this).offset();
        myPos.bottom = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        myPos.right = $(this).offset().left + $(this).outerWidth();
        
        if (myPos.bottom > e.pageY && e.pageY > myPos.bottom - 16 && myPos.right > e.pageX && e.pageX > myPos.right - 16) {
            $(this).css({ cursor: "nw-resize" });
        }
        else {
            $(this).css({ cursor: "" });
        }
    })
    //  the following simple make the textbox "Auto-Expand" as it is typed in
    .keyup(function(e) {
        //  this if statement checks to see if backspace or delete was pressed, if so, it resets the height of the box so it can be resized properly
        if (e.which == 8 || e.which == 46) {
            $(this).height(parseFloat($(this).css("min-height")) != 0 ? parseFloat($(this).css("min-height")) : parseFloat($(this).css("font-size")));
        }
        //  the following will help the text expand as typing takes place
        while($(this).outerHeight() < this.scrollHeight + parseFloat($(this).css("borderTopWidth")) + parseFloat($(this).css("borderBottomWidth"))) {
            $(this).height($(this).height()+1);
        };
    });
}
```

then I call it under `$(document).ready`

it works great, but the one problem I have is when typing in textareas this applies too, and if the page has many textareas it takes a long time to apply the resizing and will stop the page from responding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the "page not responding" problem is with your loop. Your loop is executed on each key stroke. So I decided to replace it with an `IF` condition instead.

Here's the updated code:

```
function textarea_resize() {
    //  changes mouse cursor when highlighting loawer right of box
    $("textarea.autoresize").on('keyup', function(e) {
        var myPos = $(this).offset();
        myPos.bottom = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        myPos.right = $(this).offset().left + $(this).outerWidth();
        
        if (myPos.bottom > e.pageY && e.pageY > myPos.bottom - 16 && myPos.right > e.pageX && e.pageX > myPos.right - 16) {
            $(this).css({ cursor: "nw-resize" });
        }
        else {
            $(this).css({ cursor: "" });
        }
    })
    //  the following simple make the textbox "Auto-Expand" as it is typed in
    .keyup(function(e) {
        //  this if statement checks to see if backspace or delete was pressed, if so, it resets the height of the box so it can be resized properly
        if (e.which == 8 || e.which == 46) {
            $(this).height(parseFloat($(this).css("min-height")) != 0 ? parseFloat($(this).css("min-height")) : parseFloat($(this).css("font-size")));
        }
        //  the following will help the text expand as typing takes place
        var new_height = this.scrollHeight + parseFloat($(this).css("borderTopWidth")) + parseFloat($(this).css("borderBottomWidth"));
        if( $(this).outerHeight() < new_height ) {
            $(this).height(new_height);
        }
    });
}

$(function(){
 textarea_resize();
});
```

It seemed working, and I didn't went through the logic. Maybe you can tweak/rework it to suit your needs.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3qk7tjhv/

Comment: nice, seems to work although its not resizing on page load anymore?

Comment: i added this code to the function which solved the above ^ `$('textarea.autoresize').trigger('keyup');`

Comment: Glad to know that you found the solution! Cheers :)